# How to use OAuth 2 - OAuth 2 C# example

Tags: c#, oauth, oauth-2.0, dotnetopenauth

I have to figure out how to use OAuth 2 in order to use Deviantart api.

I got the client_id and client_secret part

Here the information they give

Endpoints

The only information you need to authenticate with us using OAuth 2.0 are the `client_id` and `client_secret` values for your app, as well as the endpoint shown below.

OAuth 2.0 draft 10:

https://www.deviantart.com/oauth2/draft10/authorize
https://www.deviantart.com/oauth2/draft10/token

OAuth 2.0 draft 15:

https://www.deviantart.com/oauth2/draft15/authorize
https://www.deviantart.com/oauth2/draft15/token

Placebo call

The first API call relying on OAuth 2.0 authentication is the placebo call. 
It's useful for checking that an access token is still valid before making a real API call that might be long, like a file upload. 
You call it with one of the following endpoints (an access token must be provided):

https://www.deviantart.com/api/draft10/placebo
https://www.deviantart.com/api/draft15/placebo

You need to use the endpoint that corresponds to the OAuth 2.0 draft you've obtained your token with.

It always returns the following JSON: `{status: "success"}`

I have searched the web and found this awesome library.

DotNetOpenAuth v4.0.1

http://www.dotnetopenauth.net/

Added it as reference but have no idea what to do next. Even a very small example would be really useful about how to use OAuth 2

```
using DotNetOpenAuth;
using DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth2;
```

Here the page where deviantart gives the information

http://www.deviantart.com/developers/oauth2

Ok here what i got so far but not working

```
public static WebServerClient CreateClient() {
    var desc = GetAuthServerDescription();
    var client = new WebServerClient(desc, clientIdentifier: "myid");
    client.ClientCredentialApplicator = ClientCredentialApplicator.PostParameter("mysecret");
    return client;
}

public static AuthorizationServerDescription GetAuthServerDescription() {
    var authServerDescription = new AuthorizationServerDescription();
    authServerDescription.AuthorizationEndpoint = new Uri(@"https://www.deviantart.com/oauth2/draft15/authorize");
    authServerDescription.TokenEndpoint = new Uri(@"https://www.deviantart.com/oauth2/draft15/token");
    authServerDescription.ProtocolVersion = ProtocolVersion.V20;
    return authServerDescription;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried looking at the DNOA samples? http://www.dotnetopenauth.net/

Comment: yes but not working. updated the question

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Easiest thing to do now is get Visual Studio 2013 and create a new ASP.NET Web Application choosing "Individual User Accounts" as your authentication type. There's a working OAuth 2 implementation out of the box in there (configured at App_Start\Startup.Auth.cs) which you can slice out and then adapt to your needs.

Comment: I would prefer client based such as wpf if possible

Comment: The MVC application uses OAuth1 as opposed to OAUth2.

Comment: Microsoft.Security.OWIN.OAuth uses OAuth 2:- http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth/

Answer (score 1):

In the ASP.NET Core Security Project there is now a ready to use solution:

Nuget Package: [AspNet.Security.OAuth.DeviantArt](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AspNet.Security.OAuth.DeviantArt/)