# jQuery webAPI call WebSecurity.IsAuthenticated is always false

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-web-api

I am using a WebAPI service in my webapplication. In this service is used for all account functions (/api/account/login, /api/account/logout, ...). Within the same webroot I have a website which uses this webAPI service to communicate with the backend system. So from my C# code i'm calling the IsLoggedIn function in my WebAPI which returns true when I'm logged in. This is working great.

```
[HttpGet]
public bool IsLoggedIn()
{
    return (WebSecurity.IsAuthenticated);
}
```

In my arearegistration i added the following code:

```
context.Routes.MapHttpRoute("Account", "api/account/{action}/{id}", new { Controller = "Account", id = RouteParameter.Optional });
```

And the follwing GlobalConfiguration:

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Filters.Add(new ExceptionHandlingAttribute());
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.Clear();
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.Add(new JsonMediaTypeFormatter());
```

The custom ExceptionHandlingAttribute checks if the thrown exception is of a specific type and returns a custom ReasonPhrase, so nothing special.

When I'm logged in and call the function from javascript (jQuery) or in Fiddler the IsLoggedIn function returns false. What should I add to my jQuery call to make sure the the right user is still found in the WebAPI? This is happening for POST and GET calls.

Please help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will always be false as REST is stateless, each request knows nothing about previous requests.

You could enable Session State by doing something like this
http://www.strathweb.com/2012/11/adding-session-support-to-asp-net-web-api/

A better approach would be to have your Login call return a token which is then passed on subsequent calls to identify the user.  Here's an example:
[How to use OAuth 2 - OAuth 2 C# example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14876126/how-to-use-oauth-2-oauth-2-c-sharp-example)

Comment: Still this is strange.. the server side code connects to the same service through a HttpClient.GetAsync(). This should be stateless too then right? But when I use this function i get a positive response on WebSecurity.IsAuthenticated. When I do the same thing using jQuery I get a negative response.